# CSS not working because of selection

Tags: css

My CSS is not working and I think its got something to do with the selection levels. I have the div nested inside other divs so how do i apply the CSS (ie how to make the proper selection so that the CSS is applied). This is the code:

```
<div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="navcontainer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnHome_Click" CausesValidation="false">Home</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my question is, how do I apply the CSS to the div with id navcontainer?
Currently, this is what I have in my CSS:

```
#navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#navcontainer ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
}
```

and the CSS is not being applied. Do I have to apply a particular selection and if so how?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Or the HTML code instead of asp? Best case: both.

Comment: To apply styles to that div you must simply write for "#navcontainer", like `#navcontainer {
    background: red;  
}`. I'm not sure what you're looking for though

Comment: Seems like it works alright: http://jsfiddle.net/1nmfvmte/

Answer (score 0):

To apply styles to a div via its id, you can do as follows:

```css
#navcontainer ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#navcontainer ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#navcontainer {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #036;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="navcontainer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnHome_Click" CausesValidation="false">Home</asp:LinkButton>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1v6x8ygq/)

Is this what you're looking for?